# All connections on Windows Server are going through the Traefik reverse proxy set up for a Docker app replacing the SSL certificate

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, traefik

I have a Windows Server which is serving a Docker application with containerized Flask apps to our local network. I am using a Traefik reverse proxy to direct traffic to the correct container.

The web app works fine on the server and one any other local computer. However, on the server, I cannot access any other websites through the browser. I get a 'Not Secure' error. Then when I dropdown the error using Chrome (although same happens on other browsers), I get a 'Certificate is not valid' error. And when I open that error, I can see that the certificate being used is the 'Traefik Default Cert'.

This was working for a long time until the server restarted recently and I had to rebuild the Docker application. I didn't change any configurations when rebuilding. There were no significant updates when the server restarted.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my reverse proxy configuration for my docker-compose.yml file:

```
  reverse-proxy:
    restart: always
    image: traefik:v2.10.4-windowsservercore-1809
    networks:
      - net
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik=true
    command:
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.file.directory=/etc/traefik/dynamic
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
      - --providers.docker.endpoint=npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - source: \\.\pipe\docker_engine\
        target: \\.\pipe\docker_engine\
        type: npipe
      - .\zzz-etc\traefik:c:\etc\traefik\dynamic
      - .\zzz-etc\certs:c:\etc\certs
```

I'm using custom certificates using this configuration in my certs-traefik.yml:

```
tls:
  certificates:
    - certFile: /etc/certs/cert.crt
      keyFile: /etc/certs/cert_decrypted.key
```

Comment: Are you using `localhost` as the host name when you try to access the sites from the host? And do you route traffic based on the hostname?

Comment: @HansKilian Thanks for the questions. I believe the traffic is routed based on hostname. Each container is served on a port and then depending on the subdomain used, the reverse proxy will send the traffic to the corresponding port. At least I'm pretty sure that's how reverse proxies works. And no, I am not using localhost. I have a domain that's available locally. And I had someone set it up for me, but basically if your on the network and you go to the specific domain, it routes you to the exposed ports of the server, which I believe would be 80 and 443.